# Nginx and Cloudflare with shoutcast get real ip's

Tags: nginx, cloudflare, shoutcast

So I currently have a server running with nginx on it and shoutcast. I'm running `Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-52-generic x86_64)`.

Using cloudflare I link a subdomain (using an A record) to my IP. That subdomain is proxied to mypi:8000 to access the shoutcast verver, using that domain.

Now, I get on shoutcast the plain IP on the server for every connected client, so every IP is the same nad I can't have unique listeners.

Here is my Nginx config:

```
##
# Default server configuration
##

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;


        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name rallypodium.be www.rallypodium.be;

        if ($http_host = rallypodium.be){
                rewrite  (.*)  https://www.rallypodium.be$1;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_cache phpcache; # The name of the cache key-zone to use
                fastcgi_cache_valid 200 30m; # What to cache: 'Code 200' responses, for half an hour
                fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD; # What to cache: only GET and HEAD requests (not POST)
                add_header X-Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status; # Add header so we can see if the cache hits or misses

                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;                
                include fastcgi_params;

        }

}

##############################################################
# SHOUTCAST SERVER CONFIGURATION
##############################################################

server {
        listen   80;
        listen [::]:80;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name stream.rallypodium.be;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://serverip:8000;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }   
}
```

The serverIP is the same IP as where nginx runs on. So "localhost" here... Any ideas? I already tried to add `set_real_ip_from` with all the CF Ip's and then add `real_ip_header     CF-Connecting-IP;`, but that doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

Check this Cloudflare article about how to [restore original visitor IP](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170706-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-Nginx-)

Basically, you need to use the [ngx_http_realip_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) and this conf:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name   www.example.com;

    # cloudflare
    set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
    set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
    set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
    set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
    set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;

    real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;

    # ...
}
```

Keep up to date the IP's using: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips

Also try:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_cf_connecting_ip;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: @Robin did you try `proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_cf_connecting_ip;`?

Comment: Maybe this screen helps a bit? https://image.prntscr.com/image/kbnGraO1Su6lSg8Lp7N4zw.jpeg So I have a client (myself) connected, but that's the server's IP, it has to be my IP and the source gives me `serverIP (MyIP)`

Comment: I have the with-http_realip_module installed on nginx.